# How do i add JavaFX elements with a loop?

Tags: java, loops, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am creating a mini social media with JavaFX and SQL, where users can create posts. I have each post in a Pane element, that includes the name of the user, date of the post and the text in the post. I would like to create a loop, that inserts however many posts that exist. I simply need to know, how I can create a loop that inserts for an example 5 identical pane elements. 
I am writing my code in a fxml file. I also have a controller where I can write functions. 
I can't write java code in the fxml file where the javafx elements exists, so I need to insert the pane elements via a loop in the controller somehow.

Example of code:
I haven't writted the code, i'm just asking for what approach I should take.
Here is what the code is going to look like:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane">
    <VBox layoutY="170.0" prefWidth="557.0">
        // Start Loop
          <Pane>
             <children>
                  <Label text="Test Person" />
                <Label text="Date of Post" />
                <TextArea text="Text in Post"/>
             </children>
          </Pane>
       // End Loop
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is an image of how the posts look:

[image]

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: You'll probably want to use a `ListView` and just let each `ListCell` handle displaying its item (i.e. use a custom cell implementation that sets your post view as the graphic of the cell). Then you just add all the posts (represented by a model class) to the `items` of the list view.

Comment: @akuzminykhI
I haven't writted the code, i'm just asking for what approach I should take.
I have sketched out what the code is going to look like, it's updated above :)

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the reply! Looks like that would work, i'll test it tomorrow :)

Comment: @slaw I can't really figure out a way to do that without using more libraries like JFoenix. In JavaFX it won't let me do custom cells.

Comment: Of course core JavaFX lets you use custom cells, it's one of the major features of the virtualized controls (i.e. `ListView`, `TableView`, `TreeTableView`, and `TreeView`). Create a `ListView` and set its `cellFactory` property.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you so much for the example! A bit more complex than what I was hoping for, but gets the job done. It won't let me mark your comment as the solution.

Comment: @Slaw Can you help answer a question to your code? You would help me a ton finishing my exam project. Can i message you somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
String template = "" +
            "<AnchorPane id=\"AnchorPane\">\n" +
            "    <VBox layoutY=\"170.0\" prefWidth=\"557.0\">\n" +
            "        // Start Loop\n" +
            "          <Pane>\n" +
            "             <children>\n" +
            "                  <Label text=\"%text person%\" />\n" +
            "                <Label text=\"%date of post%\" />\n" +
            "                <TextArea text=\"%text in post%\"/>\n" +
            "             </children>\n" +
            "          </Pane>\n" +
            "       // End Loop\n" +
            "    </VBox>\n" +
            "</AnchorPane>";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //Loop through the posts
    for (int i = 0; i<postNumber; i++) {
        sb.append(
                template
                        .replaceAll("%text person%", thePerson)
                        .replaceAll("%date of post%", theDate)
                        .replaceAll("%text in post%", text));
    }
    String outer =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<?import java.lang.*?>\n" +
            "<?import java.util.*?>\n" +
            "<?import javafx.scene.*?>\n" +
            "<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>\n" +
            "<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<AnchorPane xmlns=\"http://javafx.com/javafx\"\n" +
            "            xmlns:fx=\"http://javafx.com/fxml\"\n" +
            "            fx:controller=\"me.mkdomain.deeplearning.D\"\n" +
            "            prefHeight=\"400.0\" prefWidth=\"600.0\">\n" +
            "%content%\n" +
            "</AnchorPane>";
    String done = outer.replaceAll("%content%", sb.toString());
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.fxml");
    out.write(done.getBytes());
    out.close();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.load(new FileInputStream("myfile.fxml"));
```

Comment: You can, and _should_, edit your original answer if you want to add more information to it.